# Selection of a letter in a text in a matrix

Tags: python

I am a total beginner in python.
I need to autogenerate an email.
I have the following info

```
# following list in the order of Forname, familyname, birthyear
info = [['Jens','Jensen',1993],
       ['Hans','Hansen',1992],
       ['John','Johnsen',1991],
       ['Anders','Andersen',1990],
       ['David','Davidsen',1989]]
```

The condition of the email is the First letter in the first name, 5 first letter in the family name and the last two number in the birth year. 
An ex of an email: J.Jense.93@python.com

So far I have the following code:

```
 for info_fn_fl, in info[0][0][0]:
     print info_fn_fl
 J
```

Hope you can help.

Comment: What's exactly your problem? Is your code not working? Or you need to add the other information to your email address?

Comment: Are you using python 2?

Comment: Yes - 2.7. 
But I am been helped - and thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try doing this

```
for i in info:
    id_val = i[0][0]+'.'+i[1][:5]+'.'+str(i[2])[-2:]
    print(id_val)
```

#### Output

> J.Jensen.93
>   H.Hansen.92
>   J.Johnse.91
>   A.Anders.90
>   D.Davids.89

Comment: Thx - it helped!

Comment: In the family name, it's first 5 letters, not 6.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this,

```
In [11]: for fname,family_name,byear in info:
...:     print '{}.{}.{}@python.com'.format(fname[0],family_name[:5],str(byear)[2:])
...:     
J.Jense.93@python.com
H.Hanse.92@python.com
J.Johns.91@python.com
A.Ander.90@python.com
D.David.89@python.com
```